# Running Selenium test on nUnit not executing scripts

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When I was running my tests on C#-visualnUnit it runs successfully but when I was running it on Nunit only and just having the dll on the project it out puts like this:

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=49771
version=23.0.1240.0
log=\chromedriver.log

[1220/011848:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(738)] Canceling pending sends
[1220/011848:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(738)] Canceling pending sends
[1220/011848:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(738)] Canceling pending sends
[18104:3564:1220/011849:ERROR:window_impl.cc(55)]Failed to unregister class Chrome_WidgetWin_0. Error = 1412
```

I was having multithreading here. It works just fine with my vs and visualnUnit. The problem was when I tried to run it in Nunit only.

I am declaring `IWebdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` in visualNunit and vs it doesn't spawn any cmd and runs smoothly while with using Nunit it only spawns cmd prompts of its driver and doesn't continues the flow.

The system I am running on is: Windows7 64bit.

Comment: Can you please post the code as well?

Comment: ohh sorry for asking this....i have found out that it was my code that has an error...on getting some values from app.config (`var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
return appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["SeleniumHost"].Value;` nunit doesn't read this so i have changed it to `return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TrueSampleHost"];`  but million of thanks for spending some time on this....sorry

Comment: but i am a bit curious why is it in using vs and visualnunit in calling the driver it doesn't spawn a cmd window while with using nunit and a dll on the project it spawns cmd window?....does anyone know this...just out of curiosity

Comment: Hi Wendell - if you've found a solution to your problem then you should post it as an answer yourself and then accept it, to remove the question from the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the wrong return statement.

Should be something like:

```
 return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SampleHost"];
```

Comment: sorry to say this but i kind of a mention it already in my comment...but thanks for sharing your idea...